# Ruby on Rails - Cannot convert nil into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have written a simple little function that refreshes the page every 60 seconds for the purpose of a 'Time.now.strftime' function. However, when I execute a search and it eventually comes round to refreshing the page with the search results I get the following error which I cannot figure out:

can't convert nil into String

```
app/models/product.rb:37:in `+'
app/models/product.rb:37:in `fuzzy_search'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:92:in `search'

def self.fuzzy_search(search_string)
    (LINE 37)   search_string = "%" + search_string + "%"
        self.find(:all, :conditions => ["title LIKE ?", search_string])
    end

(LINE 92) @products = Product.fuzzy_search(params[:search_string])
        if @products.empty?
            flash.now[:alert] = "No records found - displaying all records..."
            @products = Product.find :all, :order => 'title'
        end
        render :action => "index"
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if you don't provide a `search_string` parameter in the request:

```
search_string = params[:search_string] # nil
```

Instead of running the search with a `nil` argument, it probably makes sense to handle the unexpected emptiness:

```
unless params[:search_string].nil?
  @products = Product.fuzzy_search(params[:search_string])
else
  abort('Search with something!') # don't actually do this
end
```

Even better, just check for the `key` in params:

```
if params.key?(:search_string)
  # do search
else
  # panic
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You param `search_string` is `nil`

I would modify `fuzzy_search`

```
def self.fuzzy_search(search_string)
  return [] unless search_string
  self.find(:all, :conditions => ["title LIKE ?", "%#{search_string}%"])
end
```

With this change, `@products` would be empty and your code would hit the `@products.empty?` condition and flash an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate your string a little differently, it won't matter that the search string is nil. Try it like this, instead: `search_string = "%#{ search_string }%"`. This will result in anything in `#{}` being cast to a string.

Comment: This should result in all records being returned, for an empty search, unlike the other proposed solutions, which return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the string "%" attempting to be concatenated to NilClass (nil).

The quickest fix would be to do the following.

The code on LINE 37:

```
search_string = "%" + search_string + "%"
```

should be changed to:

```
search_string = "%#{search_string}%"
```

Kyle's suggestion to refactor the method is also a good one.